# Why am I getting memory leaks (segmentation faults from this initialization)?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
struct node {
    void *info;
    struct node *nextNode;
}

struct linked {
    struct node* Head;
    struct node* Tail;
}

struct linked* pro[32]

void initialize_list()
     printf("seg 1\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if(!(pro[i] = (struct linked *) malloc(sizeof(struct linked)))) {
        pro[i]->Head = pro[i]->Tail = NULL;
        }
     }
     printf("seg 2\n");
}
```

I don't know why but when I call the initialize_list() function in main

```
int main() {
    initialize_list();
}
```

I sometimes get the output:

```
seg 1 
segmentation fault
```

and sometimes

```
seg 1 
seg 2
```

What I mean by sometimes, is that when I run the program for 8 times lets say, it might run with the correct output in 6 runs and in 2 runs it might produce the segmentation fault output.
Can you help me try to figure out what is wrong with this initialization? and why is it making some memory leaks I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!(pro[i] = (struct linked *) malloc(sizeof(struct linked)))) {
```

should be

```
if((pro[i] = (struct linked *) malloc(sizeof(struct linked)))) {
```

or better yet (don't cast `malloc`):

```
if((pro[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct linked)))) {
```

otherwise you tell to initialize the members when `malloc` fails

Notice that you can also use `calloc`, in such case there is no need to initialize the members to `NULL`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
     pro[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct linked));
     if (pro[i] == NULL) // And always check the return
     {
         perror("calloc");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
 }
```

Comment: but will I need to set the head and tail to NULL after using calloc? so after the if statement?

Comment: No, there is no need to initialize `head` and `tail` with `NULL` when `calloc` is used,  `calloc` fill all bytes with zeroes and a pointer with all bytes set to zero is equivalent to `(void *)0` --> `NULL` in practice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your comparison:

```
if(!(pro[i] = (struct linked *) malloc(sizeof(struct linked)))) {
    pro[i]->Head = pro[i]->Tail = NULL;
}
```

This will only evaluated to true if `malloc` return NULL.  So if the condition is true, you're attempting to dereference a NULL pointer.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means your program may or may not crash.

You instead want to assign to `pro[i]->Head` if `malloc` does not return NULL.  Also, there's no need to cast the return value of `malloc`.

```
if((pro[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct linked)))) {
    pro[i]->Head = pro[i]->Tail = NULL;
}
```

Comment: but why isn't it `if((pro[i] = (struct linked*) malloc(sizeof(struct linked))))`

Comment: @HashimAlhasanii See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc